# How to remove : after a + or - in python

Tags: python, string, parsing, datetime, timezone

i have a timestamp that looks like this `2015-11-06T14:20:14.011+01:00`. I would like to parse it to datetime. 
I have the idea that i can use `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z` as representation of this.

But the problem is the colon in the timezone. How can i remove the colon in the Timezone or is there a better way as the `%z`?

Comment: will the `:` always be the third to last character?

Comment: `s.rsplit(':', 1)[0]` would be everything up to the last colon.

Comment: `%z` (lower case) is the representation for timezone in +/- HHMM format.

Comment: SirParselot: If the User has no timezone set in the api the timezone is missing. 

DanielRoseman: i have no test system and on the python doc website it's mention in another way. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian yes it is, but hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an ISO 8601 datetime string. Don't bother parsing it or fiddling with it by hand (see: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Use the [iso8601](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/) library for Python.

```
import iso8601
parsed = iso8601.parse_date("2015-11-06T14:20:14.011+01:00")
```

If you want to remove the timezone information from it, use the `replace` method.

```
tz_stripped = parsed.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Comment: do you know if `iso8601` is in the default python?

Comment: No, you need to install it from PyPI.

Comment: ok, thank you. I have copied the File in the same folder and it works. So i do not need to install.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
original = '2015-11-06T14:20:14.011+01:00'
replaced = re.sub(r'([+-]\d+):(\d+)$', r'\1\2', original)
# replaced == '2015-11-06T14:20:14.011+0100'
```

This will replace the colon only when it is preceded by a plus or minus, and surrounded by digits until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is with dateutils
https://labix.org/python-dateutil

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
original = '2015-11-06T14:20:14.011+01:00'
print "Original Date {}".format(original)
new_date =  parse(original)
print new_date
print type(new_date)
# print new_date.hour
# print new_date.minute
# print new_date.second
print "New Date 1 {}".format(new_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print "New Date 2 {}".format(new_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
```

Output:

```
Original Date 2015-11-06T14:20:14.011+01:00
2015-11-06 14:20:14.011000+01:00
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
New Date 1 2015-11-06 14:20:14
New Date 2 2015-11-06T14:20:14.011000+0100
```

Regards